# Error installing SQL Server 2008 R2 any version. Error code: 1605

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008

> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> MsiGetProductInfo failed to retrieve ProductVersion for package with Product Code = '{DF167CE3-60E7-44EA-99EC-2507C51F37AE}'. Error code: 1605..

What I've done so far:

1. Had to re-install Windows 7 because I kept getting a pop up that said my windows was unregistered, which it wasn't (known bug) so I re-installed as per MS recommendation.
2. Un-installed SQL Server 2008 + ran Microsoft Fix It tool.
3. Tried to re-install.
4. After I got the error I deleted all the registry entries per instructions available where others have posted this same problem.
5. When I continued to get the error I renamed the registry directory UpgradeCodes to UpgradeCodes.old.
6. I've rebooted after every step and I've repeated this many times...

In all cases when I try to re-install it fails with Error code: 1605. At this point when I search the registry for the reversed key it is not found. It's gone.

Not sure what to do next.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please add summary.txt in question this link will help you locate it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I got this fixed at last. What I ended up doing is deleting the registry keys 20 or 30 times before it finally went through. It took about 3 days but it's up and running now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and following method which I got it from http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ worked for me:

Method 2

This method is a little risky but should work at the first attempt. Make sure you don’t reboot the system until we complete the process. In this method we will just make the UpgradeCodes unusable until we finish the SQL install.

1. First setup is exit the install and shutdown all the applications
2. Then go toregistry and create a backup of the registry.
3. Now go to HKEY_Classes_Root\Installer\UpgradeCodes.
4. Right click on UpgradeCodes and click on Export and type in UC.reg and save it somewhere (Maybe Desktop)
5. Then right click again and click on rename and rename to UpgradeCodes.old
6. Now attempt to install SQL again. This time it should work in first try. Make sure you don’t reboot the system because sometime other application like MS Office might stop working. Once the installation is complete, close the installer and find the file you saved UC.reg and double click on it and click OK.
7. Now we have up the UpgradeCodes back again.